# Images not displaying

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Images do not display on Chrome (and Firefox) anymore, the alt-text shows correctly.

> [image: images not displaying]

Clicking on their source reveals a page not found.

[image: page not found chrome]

I'm using *Chrome 73 on Windows 8.1* from Berlin, Germany.

---

Update: The images have been restored, it seems to be a problem somewhere between my router and the internet provider.

Comment: The images are hosted on i.stack.imgur.com, and I can see them alright. Is your ISP/firewall/office/whatever blocking imgur.com?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is too localized in its current form and is unlikely to be applicable outside of a very narrow context.